# Descargar un archivo de Firebase Storage desde Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la cual deseo poder descargar un archivo JSON de algún servidor para después ser consumido en el dispositivo localmente (para poder alimentar ciertas activities con información).

Esto lo hago para poder actualizar la información de manera remota y que así sea actualizada sin la necesidad de lanzar una nueva actualización con la nueva información en la Play Store.

Actualmente estoy usando Firebase. Entonces subi un archvo al Cloud Storage  del mismo y lo estoy intentando descargar. EL codigo que utilice es el siguiente:

```
private void downloadfile() {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/......");

    File localFile = null;
    try {
        localFile = File.createTempFile("dishes", "json");
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    httpsReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Se descargo bien", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error al descragar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

EL codigo lo saque de la documentacion ofcial de Firebase.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?hl=es-419

Segun esto, el archivo si se descarga, pero no puedo encontrarlo por ningun lado. Cual es el error? O como puedo ubicar mi archivo?

PD:
Utilizo el .getAbsolutePath() para mostrame donde se "guardo", pero la ruta que me muestra no existe.

```
File localFile = null;
Utilio el metodo localFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: pues firebase cuenta con storage y real databse que los puedes combinar, en el primero almacenas el archivo json, y en el segundo actualizas algún nodo que le notifique a tu app de dicha actualización, ahora el procedimiento es sencillo en realidad, pero ya has intentado algo????? porque la documentación de firebase al respecto esta más que clara para lo que deseas, en caso contrario, comparte el código con el cual intentaste realizar la tarea, y las ultimas versiones de AE prácticamente te hacen el trabajo de enlazarte todo a firebase

Comment: Seria mucho más simple que subieras los datos del archivo a Cloud Firestore(base de datos de firebase), y luego los consumieras de manera normal, es más pesado para tu aplicación(consume más ancho de banda) tener que bajar un archivo y luego consumir datos de este, ademas que la facilidad de Firebase es dejar que se encargue de todo el Backend y consumir los datos directamente, podrías, en Node, poner un trigger que salte tcada que subes el archivo, este se encarga de pasar los datos a CloudFirestore y luego la aplicación mediante métodos convencionales consume estos datos ya actualizados.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, trabajo con firebase en el trabajo y lo usamos muchisimo, te comento como funciona, si subes un archivo json desde tu computadora la referencia va a tener que ser unica al archivo y la referencia va a tener que ser por storage , lo cual si luego necesitas actualizar automaticamente ese json, no vas a poder ya que el childEventListener que tiene database no se dara cuenta cuando cambie ese archivo en el storage ya que no cambio nada de la base de datos.

Que te sugiero

Subir el archivo json desde el telefono con firebase , generar la downloadURL y ponerla en tu base de datos con setValue, de esta forma vas a poder acceder siempre a la ubicacion de tu archivo

Solamente basta con bajar el archivo con getFile y luego descomprimirlo a un directorio para poder leerlo luego

Te dejo un hint de como subo yo un json desde android a firebase

```
public Boolean subirJson(final DatabaseReference mDatabase, StorageReference mStorageRef)
    {
        Principal.Eljson().GuardarJson(Principal.getMiJson(), "ejemplo.txt");

        final StorageReference referenciaJson = mStorageRef;
        try {
            ejemplo = mContext.openFileInput("ejemplo.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        referenciaJson.putStream(ejemplo).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                mDatabase.setValue(downloadUrl.toString(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference referenciaJson) {
                        if(referenciaJson!=null){

                            Log.d("TAG", "Se guardo correctamente url");
                        }else{
                            Log.d("TAG", "Error al subir url");
                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
        return  false;
    }
```

Para obtenerlos es mas o menos el mismo proceso

```
    mDatabase.child("Usuario").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("URL_Archivos").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                Log.e("Descarga","Existen Datos");

                                //Creamos donde se van a guardar los archivos, en este caso en cache momentaneo
                                File rootPath = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(),"Archivos);
                                if(!rootPath.exists()) {
                                    rootPath.mkdirs();//si no existe el directorio lo creamos
                                }
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Archivos").child("Json").child("ejemplo" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail() + "txt");

                                final File jsonActualizado = new File(rootPath, "ejemplo.txt");


                                mStorageRef.getFile(jsonActualizado).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {




                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                    }
 }
 }
```

Espero te sirva la informacion !

Comment: La info la estas guardando en el cache del dispositivo, no? En mi caso me conviene mas guardar fisicamente el archivo (Ya actualice mi pregunta con el codigo que tengo). Como le haces para especificar la ruta de guardado? Gracias de antemano.